# Excel не отображает рисунки

Tags: excel, vba

Есть множество excel файлов с рисунками, и для удобства разработал в отдельном файле excel макрос, который копирует все листы выбранного файла из этого множества. Что кучка файлов, что сам excel с макросом хранится на сетевом шаре, и проблема в том, что у части пользователей при копировании картинки отображаются корректно, а у остальных нет.. Пишет, что "не удаётся отобразить рисунок с красным крестиком". Рисунки в файлах прикреплены **не по ссылке**, т.е они зашиты в файл.
В чем же может быть проблема?
Код копирования листов из файла

```
Private Sub CopySheets(ByVal Path As String) 
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim oWbk As Workbook
    Set oWbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
            For Each Item In oWbk.Sheets
                    oWbk.Sheets(Item.Name).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
            Next
    oWbk.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: Наверное, красный крестик в рисунке раздражает программу :) Как помочь? Описание общее, примера нет... Может, Ваш макрос шалит...

Comment: @vikttur Вот стандартный код копирования файлов(вставил в вопрос), но не думаю, что в этом проблема, т.к как я написал у части пользователей работает корректно

Answer (score 0):

Не дочитал до конца, в итоге не то написал :)
Всё зависит видимо от версии офиса и установленных компонентов.
А может тривиально - у тех у кого не отображается "крестик" - нет на чтение прав.

Comment: Права у всех идентичные. Проблема только с картинками, помимо них таблицы копируются нормально

Answer (score 0):

Не следует переменые называть зарезервированными словами (`Item`, `Path`). Даже если причина причина потери рисунков не в этом...

```
Private Sub CopySheets(ByVal sPath As String)
Dim wBook As Workbook, sht As Worksheet
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .DisplayAlerts = False: End With
    Set wBook = ThisWorkbook

    With Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sPath)
        For Each sht In .Sheets
            sht.Copy After:=wBook.Worksheets(wBook.Worksheets.Count)
        Next sht

        .Close
    End With

    Set wBook = Nothing
    With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .DisplayAlerts = True: End With
End Sub
```